# How to sum up the first 5 list values in the list of numbers in the earth engine

Tags: arrays, list, image, var, google-earth-engine

Let the var t = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]. 
I want to sum up the first 5 values in the list and print the number. I want the number 15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you can:

```
var t = ee.List([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
var t2 = t.slice(0,5);
print(t2.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()));
```

hope it helps,